# How to use Scrapy shell on linkedin?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm a beginner using Scrapy and am having trouble using it on linkedin.

For example:

scrapy shell "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Communications&location=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&locationId=PLACES.us.7-1-0-19-57&trk=jobs_jserp_search_button_execute&searchOrigin=JSERP&applyLogin="

The response is None.  How do I get a valid object?

Comment: Just a hint: [LinkedIn - Prohibition of Scraping Software](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibition-of-scraping-software?lang=en)

Comment: I'm not a member of LinkedIn.

Comment: probably your request is filtered, your bot can be detected in several ways and the alternatives you have to overcome this filters do break some web crawler ethics.

Comment: Also take a look at their [robots.txt](https://www.linkedin.com/robots.txt) content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just making an try example, do this:

```
import requests
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

r = requests.get('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search?keywords=Communications&location=Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&locationId=PLACES.us.7-1-0-19-57&trk=jobs_jserp_search_button_execute&searchOrigin=JSERP&applyLogin=')

response = TextResponse(r.url, body=r.text, encoding='utf-8')
```